# How to transform a flat JSON to nested JSON using NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Input JSON :

```
{

  "type": "mbrInfo",
  "csId": 123456789,
  "insTS": "14-07-201911:55",
  "seqId": 1234565,
  "title": "Mr",
  "fName": "Amit",
  "mName": "",
  "lName": "V",
  "suffix": "Engg",
  "lvlId": "P",
  "lvlType": "LAC",
  "acctStatus": "20",
  "enrlDT": "2016-08-29",
  "vrsnId": 1
}
```

Expected Output JSON:

```
{

  "type": "mbrInfo",
  "csId": 123456789,
  "insTS": "14-07-201911:55",
  "seqId": 1234565,
   "name" : [{
  "title": "Mr",
  "fName": "Amit",
  "mName": "",
  "lName": "V",
  "suffix": "Engg"}],
  "lvlId": "P",
  "lvlType": "LAC",
  "acctStatus": "20",
  "enrlDT": "2016-08-29",
  "vrsnId": 1
}.
```

Currently I am using JOLTtransformJSON processor with JOLT Spec as :

```
[
{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "name": {
        "$": "[#1]",
        "@.title": "[#1].title",
        "@.fName": "[#1].fName",
        "@.mName": "[#1].mName",
        "@.lName": "[#1].lName",
        "@.suffix": "[#1].suffix"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But all I am getting is either NULL or the original JSON (with diff spec) as output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oscar , if you look carefully you will find the input json to be a flat json whereas the output one is nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the intent to put all the name fields into a 1-element array containing an object. This JOLT spec puts them into an object at the `name` field:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "title": "name.title",
      "fName": "name.fName",
      "mName": "name.mName",
      "lName": "name.lName",
      "suffix": "name.suffix",
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

...and this spec puts them into a 1-element array at the `name` field:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "title": "name[0].title",
      "fName": "name[0].fName",
      "mName": "name[0].mName",
      "lName": "name[0].lName",
      "suffix": "name[0].suffix",
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

I don't see any other place in the input to get an index into the array, so I just used `0`.

Comment: @mattyb , please can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693401/nifi-distributedcache-lookup-issue