# Nifi DistributedCache lookup issue

Tags: apache-nifi

I have configured a flow as follows:

1. `GetFile`
2. `SplitText` -> splitting into flowfiles
3. `ExtractText` -> adding attributes with two keys
4. `PutDistributedMapCache` -> Cache Entry Identifier is ${Key1}_${Key2}

Now I configured one sample `GenerateFlowFile` which generates a sample record and then goes into `LookupRecord` `( concat(/Key1,'_',/Key2))` which looks for the same key in cache.

I see a problem in my caching flow because when I configure a GenerateFlowFile to cache same records , I am able to do lookup

This flow is not able to lookup. Please help

Flow is:
[image]

PutDistributedMapCache

[image]

ExtractText

[image]

Lookup flow

[image]

LookupRecord Config

[image]

**I have added four keys in total because that is my business use case.**

I have a csv file with 53 records and I use Splitfile to split each record and add attributes which act as my key which I store in PutDistributedMapcache. Now I have a different flow where in I start with a  GenerateFlowFile which generates a record like this :

[image]

So I expect my LookupKeyRecord which has a jsonreader and jsonwriter to read this record , lookup with the key in the distributedcache and populate the /Feedback field in my record.

This fails to look up records and records goes as UNMATCHED.

Now the catch is lets say I remove GetFile and use a GenerateFlowFile with this config to cache :

[image]

so my lookup works with the keys 9_9_9_9. But the moment I add another set of records with different keys , my lookup fails.

Comment: what is this: `concat(/Key1,'_',/Key2)` ? Could you edit your question and provide all parameters of the LookupRecord  and PutDistributedMapCache processors

Comment: I have added the configs

Comment: @daggett . Can you suggest me with this problem

Comment: now describe your problem. provide example of json + avro schema for it. why you have to use LookupRecord instead of PutDistributedMapCache? the point that i can see: according to [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.lookup.DistributedMapCacheLookupService/index.html) your Record Path must contain the key `'key'`. so, it should look like: `/key[concat(...)]/...`, but to provide a full answer example of json+format is required.

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Waiting for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out , my DistributedMapCache server was having a default config of Max Cache Entries as 1. I increaded it , its working now :)